# JNA, Structures and Arrays

Tags: java, arrays, struct, jna

I'm trying to create a array of my class (that extends JNA's Structure) to pass it for a DLL function. I have the values readed from a database to a ArrayList, and now I need to put them into a array. First, I tried to use the toArray() method of ArrayList, but it return me the following exception when I call the native function:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Structure array elements must use contiguous memory (bad backing address at Structure array index 1)
```

If I simply set a new array with the same size as the ArrayList, when I will set the 'fields' of the struct in my class, it returns me a NullPointerException.

Someone can help me to solve this?

Comment: pls show the code you use to convert to array :)

Comment: It's very simple.
MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
MyClass[] myArray = (MyClass[]) myClass.toArray(sizeOfArray);

Answer (score 2):

Structure.toArray() provides you with a block of contiguously allocated Structure objects.  Create this array of Structure prior to initializing it from your ArrayList of "values".